# How can I get the source code of XmlDiffPatch library?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, open-source, xmldiff

I came across the [Microsofr.XmlDiffPatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302294.aspx) and I would like to check how the Patch algorithm works. I spent sometime searching for the source code of this library, but didn't find anything useful yet.
My questions are:

1. Is it possible to obtain this code from some online repository - is it open source?
2. If not, is there any other strategy to extract this code somehow from references in Visual Studio?

Comment: I just get the project URL here if I download and install the Nuget pacakge: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302294.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396, for the old version, I found the assembly and source code here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c28a32e9-4394-4574-a7ae-279147a8fe02/comparing-and-updating-xml-file?forum=xmlandnetfx

Comment: Although I have already referenced the library in my solution, I went through installation process (it required to install .NET 1.1), and now I have the source code available. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to know that it has been resolved, I just add it as the answer. If it is helpful, you could mark it as the answer. Have a nice day:)

Comment: Sure. To you as well! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could download and install XmlDiffPatch from here:

http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/f/1/1f146f9b-2a71-4904-8b91-e2f62d7b64b3/XmlDiffPatch.exe

And then, you could find source code in Src directory.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the installer requires .NET Framework 1.1!  So cannot run it or get it to run on any modern machine.

Comment: OK finally got .NET Framework 1.1 installed.  Sheesh! The next problem is the EULA which is does not allow distribution!  "You may not modify or distribute...in any form."  If Microsoft is not going to maintain this code base, then please open it up!